# Highlight a cell if today's date falls between a date range

Tags: excel-formula

I'm currently making a data analysis spreadsheet for my work and I'm trying to conditionally format cells based on what time of year it is.

So for example, if a student has a grade A in cell A2 and today's date is between Sept 1st and Oct 20th (year isn't important) then the cell highlights green, but if the same student has the same grade between Jan 1st and Feb 19th then the cell highlights yellow.

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a new Conditional Formatting rule and choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", and the formula you enter for the case you described for green is:

```
 =AND(A2="A",OR(AND(MONTH(TODAY())=9, DAY(TODAY()) >1),AND(MONTH(TODAY())=10, DAY(TODAY()) <20)))
```

Then add another conditional formatting rule for the same cell, and choose Use a formula and use the following for the Yellow case:

```
=AND(A2="A",OR(AND(MONTH(TODAY())=1, DAY(TODAY()) >1),AND(MONTH(TODAY())=2, DAY(TODAY()) <19)))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works perfectly thanks. Is there a way I can set the same rule to check multiple cells? As it stands I've got over 500 cells with data in and 54 rules to check against date so there'd be thousands of rules if I have to set it per individual cell.

Comment: Managed to get it working exactly as I need it. Thanks for the help :)